# Windows multi-monitor setup mismatched identifying numbers [Windows 8.1]

Tags: windows-8.1, multiple-monitors

I've got a bit of a strange and rather should-not-happen problem on Windows 8.1 using multimonitor setup.

I have two Dell P2314T  23" FHD Touch screen displays which today I plugged in my Surface Pro 3 for the first time (usually I worked with 1 of them, but for various reasons today I needed both). 
Using original Docking station I plugged in two miniDP to HDMI adapters and connected them to be as second and third monitor. Voila, the picture came up, running Touch calibration wizard recognized the touch panels and all looked well -> except that it's not.

The Identifying numbers of windows are mixed up and can't be changed.

The positions of the screens are as follows:
1 (Surface Pro 3 integrated display)
2 (Dell P2314T 1, in the middle)
3 (Dell P2314T 2, on the right)

So it goes 1-2-3. However, when I press Identify button in Windows Screen resolution settings form, the monitors are identified as 1-3-2.  The forms and mouse follows the correct pattern and direction using 1-2-3 configuration, while they are identified as 1-3-2.

Anyone have any idea what could cause windows to get so confused and how to fix this?

Reboot did not help, so some more deep-explanatory options and solutions would be welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Switch the connections for monitor 2 and monitor 3 with one another.  I am going to guess the problem is the adapters.

Comment: Already did - thought this would be obvious to be done before writing to the forum ;)
The problem is not in adapters - would make no sense. Windows reports identifying number "3" to be projected to the monitor that windows itself knows is Monitor 2 in the composition view.

Comment: We are not a forum.  Have you tried not connecting the monitor identified as 2 to see what the monitor identified as 3 identifies as?

Comment: We are in my country/language... ;)

If there are only 2 connected, it's always monitor 1 and 2. Windows in no situation shows monitors 1 and 3 connected without 2 being listed as well..

I'm happy to upload a video of what's going on in case anyone is in doubt whether I'm at the right mind..

Comment: If you change the order of monitor 2-3 with each other, then restart, what happens?

Comment: Exactly the same. The system boots up just as it was left the last time. And on identify the numbers goes the same - swopped.

Comment: I am suspect the problem is either caused by the monitors (for whatever reason) or the adapters.  I have a Surface Pro 3 and don't have these problems with my identical monitors.

Comment: I don't have any issues with the two monitors used on my Zotac Magnus PC, in combination with another two U2414H pieces forming square 2x2 canvas. (using Windows 10)
I do have issues with the Surface Pro 3 itself ever since I bought it though, such as getting battery drained out until shut down without warning with the charger plugged in (both, in docking station or not docked), overheating etc (it's i7/256gb model), so if on anything, I'm putting blame on the Surface here, as the two Dells (all 4 for that matter) never ever left me surprised or disappointed in over 16 months since I got them

Comment: Windows 10 deals with multiple monitors a great deal better than Windows 8.1  Create an image of the Surface Pro 3 as it is today, upgrade it to Windows 10, see if anything changes.  Worst case you restore the image and have burned a couple hours in your spare time, or don't worry about it, since you have all three displays working without issue. Be sure you have the current firmware and Intel drivers installed though, I never had a problem with my Surface Pro 3, but I keep my updated.

Comment: That doesn't justify why 8.1 couldn't do the same, since 7 did and does flawlessly.
As a side note, the initial tests with the Surface where I ran 4 monitors, the 4th being VGA 1366x786 one using Usb 3.0 to vga china adapter did not address this issues at the time, so I'm blindguessing its either some update that caused the issue or the issue is with the identical displays being used and therefore not being distinguished as they should be...

Comment: I do have all three working, but the issue becomes trouble when the app determines display 2 with x coordinate offset of the monitor 3...

Comment: I can only provide possible explanations to the problem.  I know Windows 10 received numerous multi-display and display resolution fixes.  Windows 7 worked because it was, simply put, more dumb about displays. Windows 8.1 was partially smart about it.  As for the reasons, hardware changed between Windows 7 and Windows 10, we know have 4K displays, that wasn't a problem with Windows 7 nor Windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

1. Disconnect the third monitor's video cable (the one that Windows currently has assigned as "monitor 2").
2. Restart the computer.
3. Reconnect the third monitor. It should be reassigned as "monitor 3" now.
4. If touch settings are still wrong, try disconnecting both, restarting, connecting 1, restarting, connecting both.

Comment: Not solved the issue either. That seems like a bug that got locked in.
Not the only one though. Running another machine with Windows 10, having 2 Dell 24" non-touch displays and one Q-Touch FHD screen, I can only get the touch to work on whichever monitor is "Primary" display. The windows touch calibration setup software won't even open while this touch screen is connected. Same issue with our Alpha displays, which is a big bummer.

Answer (score 0):

Note that there is no requirement that the physical order of the monitors matches the logical order.  In my experience Windows assigns the physical numbers based on what the graphics card(s) say, but it's quite permissible to drag the monitors around so the logical order is different than the physical order.

This machine has a physical arrangement of:

```
 1
2 3 4
```

Windows handles this fine, going down off monitor 1 ends up on 2 or 3 depending on where you do it.  It's pure chance 2, 3, and 4 are in order, I made no attempt to line the cables up that way.  Before I added #1 they were in 1, 3, 2 order.  Just drag the monitors where you want, everything's fine for 99.9% of programs.  (A few, especially older programs have problems with multi-monitor setups and do things like reject negative coordinates or center a window on the entire desktop rather than a monitor.)

Comment: Windows is so broken regarding this issue (touch and touch calibration/assignment when it comes to more than 1 monitor) that I just gave up even describing. Yes, even after all these years. Its sad that MS wants to be "Apple 2" so badly.

Comment: @ThatMarc I've never worked with touchscreen monitors on Windows to have hit problems.